# How to transfer an array of objects into a HTML form

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I am a beginner in Angular and have a problem.
I want to transfer data from the back-end to the front and fill it in the HTML form. But have an error. If I understand correctly, the reason is that the form builder is triggered earlier than the answer to the query arrives.
How to fix this error?

categories.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormArray, FormBuilder, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';
import {Category} from '../../../shared/models/category';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {ProductsService} from '../../../shared/services/products.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-category',
  templateUrl: './categories.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./categories.component.scss']
})
export class CategoriesComponent implements OnInit {

  // categories = [
  //   {id: 1, name: 'veloglasses', uaName: 'Велоокуляри'},
  //   {id: 2, name: 'skiglasses', uaName: 'Лижні окуляри'},
  //   {id: 3, name: 'frames', uaName: 'Оправи'},
  //   {id: 4, name: 'accesories', uaName: 'Аксесуари'}
  // ];
  categories: Category[];

  categoryForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
              private router: Router,
              private productService: ProductsService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.productService.getCategories().subscribe(data => {
      this.categories = data;
      this.categoryForm = this.fb.group({
        categories: this.fb.array(this.categories.map(category => {this.createCategoryGroup(category), console.log(category); } ))
      });
      console.log(this.categories);
    });
  }

  createCategoryGroup(category: any = {}) {
    return this.fb.group({
      id: this.fb.control(category.id),
      name: this.fb.control(category.name),
      uaName: this.fb.control(category.uaName)
    });
  }

  addCategory() {
    this.categoriesArray.push(this.createCategoryGroup());
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.productService.createCategory(this.categories);
    console.log(this.categoryForm.value);
  }

  removeCategory(index) {
    this.categoriesArray.removeAt(index);
  }

  get categoriesArray() {
    return (this.categoryForm.get('categories') as FormArray);
  }

}
```

categories.component.html

```
<form id="productCategories" [formGroup]="categoryForm">
  <div class="form-group" formArrayName="categories">
    <div *ngFor="let category of categoriesArray.controls; let i = index;">
      <div class="row" [formGroupName]="i">
        <input class="form-control" type="number" formControlName="id">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="name">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="uaName">
        <button class="btn" type="button" (click)="removeCategory(i)">Remove</button>
        <button class="btn" type="submit" (click)="onSubmit()">Update</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn" type="button" (click)="addCategory()">Add Category</button>
</form>
```

products.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Product} from '../models/product';
import {Category} from '../models/category';

const header = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductsService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  private productsUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/products';
  private categoriesUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/products/categories';

 ...

  public createCategory(category) {
    return this.http.post<Category>(this.categoriesUrl + '/add', category);
  }

  public getCategory(category) {
    return this.http.get<Category>(this.categoriesUrl + '/' + category.id);
  }

  public getCategories() {
    return this.http.get<Category[]>(this.categoriesUrl);
  }

  public deleteCategory(category) {
    return this.http.delete(this.categoriesUrl + '/' + category.id);
  }
}
```

Comment: You should place the this.categoryForm = this.fb.group({ block in the subscribe block of the service call. (after the assign)

Comment: @TarasSvidnytskyy check first if data is arrived. after that use `this.categoryForm = this.fb.group({
      categories: this.fb.array(this.categories.map(category => {this.createCategoryGroup(category), console.log(category); } ))
    });` this line of code.

Comment: @Abhishek The data arrive. And I have these errors [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1W94QZ2NGlThEYAgwy-pxStzwEOcfmuqX) [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KkohCM8X7im6UXWlOteAQnNgjQxvxJCi) [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hDuy8urMHmh7X0Uf2qDlVTi9pEHI-ogv)

Comment: @Peter Tnank u. Did it, but I still have such errors:  [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1W94QZ2NGlThEYAgwy-pxStzwEOcfmuqX) [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KkohCM8X7im6UXWlOteAQnNgjQxvxJCi) [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hDuy8urMHmh7X0Uf2qDlVTi9pEHI-ogv)

Comment: You can use resolve guards to fetch the categories in the server before the form is loaded. ref : https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-guard

Comment: @TarasSvidnytskyy glad you got it sorted, yes you needed the initialiser as shown Avin (you should tick their answer). The resolve guards is a good idea, and should be used more IMO.

Comment: Here is your solution using resolve guards. https://stackblitz.com/edit/resolve-guard-example-griwh2?embed=1&file=src/app/categories/categories.component.ts&view=preview

Comment: @TejPatil The files are empty :(

Comment: oops...! Sorry...check this url -- https://stackblitz.com/edit/resolve-guard-example-griwh2?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an empty form array on load and patch it with the data afterwards.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    const categoryArray = this.fb.array([])
    this.categoryForm = this.fb.group({
      categories: categoryArray
    });

    this.productService.getCategories().subscribe(data => {
      this.categories = data;
      this.categories.forEach(category => {
        categoryArray.push(this.createCategoryGroup(category)); 
        console.log(category); 
      })
    });
  }
```